# How to install chainer on Bluemix?

Tags: ibm-cloud, chainer

I want to use chainer on Bluemix.
Can someone provide me how to install chainer on bluemix ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to start with the [Chainer docs](http://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tutorial/basic.html). As far as installation on the Bluemix platform, that would depend on which Bluemix services you want to invoke, such as Watson Conversation, and what you want to do with them.

Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions once you are actually working with a tool or framework such as Chainer. Please take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks. I saw chainer, but I do not well about Bluemix.